# How to filter entries by checkboxes using Sprig

Tags: craft3, plugin-sprig, category-filter

I am using the Sprig plugin to filter news entries on a news overview page. I have three checkboxes for the categories related to the news entries.

I have the page working for the basic functions by adapting code used on the [Sprigboard](https://putyourlightson.com/sprig/components/board).

But the page won't let me select multiple checkboxes. I can't figure out how to make Sprig respect all checkboxes and push the selection to the url.

I have previously done this using vanilla javascript, but I wonder if such a feature could be solved elegantly using Sprig.

Category checkboxes:

```
  {% for category in craft.categories().group('news').all() %}
  <li class="filter--content--item {{ category.id in newsCat ? 'selected' : '' }}">
      <input sprig type="checkbox" class="filter_checkbox" name="newsCat" id="checkbox_{{ category.id }}" value="{{ category.id }}" {{ category.id in newsCat ? 'checked' : '' }}>
      <label id="label_{{ category.id }}" class="newsCatLabel" for="checkbox_{{ category.id }}">
          {{ category.title }}
      </label>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
```

Search query:

```
  {% set newsCat = newsCat ?? '' %}
  {% set relatedTo = newsCat ? relatedTo|merge([newsCat]) : relatedTo %}

  {% set entryQuery = craft.entries
    .section('news')
    .limit(10)
    .relatedTo(relatedTo)
    .search(search)
  %}
  (...)
  {% do sprig.pushUrl('?' ~ {page: page, newsCat: newsCat}|url_encode) %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the following code - I just didn't come up with it earlier. I had to index the newsCat array used to denominate the single checkbox names.

```
{% set newsCat = newsCat ?? '' %}
{% set relatedTo = newsCat|join(',') %}

{% set entryQuery = craft.entries
    .section('news')
    .limit(5)
    .relatedTo(relatedTo)
%}


{% for category in craft.categories().group('news').all() %}
    <li>
        <input sprig type="checkbox" name="newsCat[{{ loop.index}}]" value="{{ category.id }}" {{ category.id in newsCat ? 'checked' :'' }}>
        <label for="checkbox_{{ category.id }}">
            {{ category.title }}
        </label>
    </li>
{% endfor %}

{% do sprig.pushUrl('?' ~ {page:page, newsCat:relatedTo}|url_encode) %}
```

Comment: Can you mark this as the correct answer so that this question appears resolved?

Comment: If you want to make the filtering exclusive instead of inclusive, just change the `relatedTo` variable to `{% set relatedTo = not newsCat ? [] : ['and']|merge(newsCat) %}`

Comment: Slight amendment to that: if you're updating the URL, and then filtering based on those query parameters, you need to make sure to convert the filters from a string to an array on the initial page load. `{% if not sprig.isRequest and craft.app.request.getQueryParam('newsCat') != '' %}
  {% set relatedTo = not newsCat ? [] : ['and']|merge(newsCat|split(',')) %}
{% else %}
  {% set relatedTo = not newsCat ? [] : ['and']|merge(newsCat) %}
{% endif %}
`

Answer (score 2):

Checkbox input field names should be in array format (not specific to Sprig), so I expect this should work.

```
<input sprig type="checkbox" class="filter_checkbox" name="newsCat[]" id="checkbox_{{ category.id }}" value="{{ category.id }}" {{ category.id in newsCat ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

Comment: That ended up in always using newsCat[0], which I tried early. Based on your input, and since you believed it should work, I investigated further and got it working using below code. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it!